# How can I limit the amount of clients in NSNetService?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, limit, nsnetservice

I've successfully created a server/client TCP connection, and now I want to stop the service advertising but DO NOT want the server to stop!, basically want to accept only 1 client.

EDIT: want to be able to add maxClients variable, so I can modify the amount of clients allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Call the NSNetServices stop method after accepting maxClients

Comment: it will leave the sockets open?